# Scroll horizontally dynamic div items

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to scroll horizontally the dive contents. but these contents are dynamically retring from db in my asp.net mvc 3 application.

I want to be split records into several columns, but on right button click only 2 column should be scrolled.  is there any simple javascript avaulable ?
i need something like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something called a carousel -> http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm